# WordPress posts page navigation not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination, navigation

First off all sorry for my English...

I already tried every possible solution I found in this and other Forums but I just don't get it:
-I've got 10 Posts and Maximum 2 are shown per Page
 -On my first Page (Home) the newest 2 Posts are shown
 -When I go to the second Page (Older Posts) the same Posts are shown
 -When I go to the third Page (Older Posts) the same two Posts are shown AND the next 2 older Posts (4 Posts are shown)
 -When I go to the fouth Page the same Posts as on the third Page AND the next 2 older Posts are shown (6 Posts are shown)
 -...and so on

So only on Page 1 and 2 the exact same Posts are shown. From Page 3 and above its adding the Posts it should, but the other Posts dont hide. The URL always changes to "/page/2/", "/page/3/"...

I also tried it with the Themes "Twenty Ten", "Twenty Eleven", "Twenty Thirteen", "Twenty Fourteen" and two random other Themes from the most popular Themes.

I also deactivated all my Plugins and tried it with the Default permalink structure. But the Problem still continued.

I think the Problem might be the index.php file in the Themes Directory. I played a Little with this File but didn't get the solution. At the Moment I've got the restored original index.php File.

Has anyone got an idea what this Problem might cause?

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the Problem:

The "WP DB abstraction plugin" caused the Problem. by following the steps on [this](http://geeks.vivavivu.com/2014/10/plugin-to-make-wordpress-work-with-sql.html) page, it resolved my Problems.